# Zooming/scaling a tiled image anchoring the zoom point to the mouse cursor

Tags: image, python-2.7, pygame

I've got a project where I'm designing an image viewer for tiled images. Every image tile is 256x256 pixels. For each level of scaling, I'm increasing the size of each image by 5%. I represent the placement of the tiles by dividing the screen into tiles the same size as each image. An offset is used to precicely place each image where needed. When the scaling reaches a certain point(1.5), I switch over to a new layer of images that altogether has a greater resolution than the previous images. The zooming method itself looks like this:

```
def zoomer(self, mouse_pos, zoom_in): #(tuple, bool)

    x, y = mouse_pos
    x_tile, y_tile = x / self.tile_size, y / self.tile_size
    old_scale = self.scale
    if self.scale > 0.75 and self.scale < 1.5:
        if zoom_in:
            self.scale += SCALE_STEP # SCALE_STEP = 5% = 0.05
            ratio = (SCALE_STEP + 1)
        else:
            self.scale -= SCALE_STEP
            ratio = 1 / (SCALE_STEP + 1)
    else:
        if zoom_in:
            self.zoom += 1
            self.scale = 0.8
            ratio = (SCALE_STEP + 1)
        else:
            self.zoom -= 1
            self.scale = 1.45
            ratio = 1 / (SCALE_STEP + 1)

    # Results in x/y lengths of the relevant full image
    x_len = self.size_list[self.levels][0] / self.power()
    y_len = self.size_list[self.levels][1] / self.power()
    # Removing extra pixel if present
    x_len = x_len - (x_len % 2)
    y_len = y_len - (y_len % 2)
    # The tile's picture coordinates
    tile_x = self.origo_tile[0] + x_tile
    tile_y = self.origo_tile[1] + y_tile
    # The mouse's picture pixel address
    x_pic_pos = (tile_x * self.tile_size) - 
                 self.img_x_offset + (x % self.tile_size)
    y_pic_pos = (tile_y * self.tile_size) - 
                 self.img_y_offset + (y % self.tile_size)
    # Mouse percentile placement within the image
    mouse_x_percent = (x_pic_pos / old_scale) / x_len
    mouse_y_percent = (y_pic_pos / old_scale) / y_len
    # The mouse's new picture pixel address
    new_x = (x_len * self.scale) * mouse_x_percent
    new_y = (y_len * self.scale) * mouse_y_percent
    # Scaling tile size
    self.tile_size = int(TILE_SIZE * self.scale)
    # New mouse screen tile position
    new_mouse_x_tile = x / self.tile_size
    new_mouse_y_tile = y / self.tile_size
    # The mouse's new tile address
    new_tile_x = new_x / self.tile_size
    new_tile_y = new_y / self.tile_size
    # New tile offsets
    self.img_x_offset = (x % self.tile_size) - int(new_x % self.tile_size)
    self.img_y_offset = (y % self.tile_size) - int(new_y % self.tile_size)
    # New origo tile
    self.origo_tile = (int(new_tile_x) - new_mouse_x_tile,
                       int(new_tile_y) - new_mouse_y_tile)
```

Now, the issue arising from this is that the `mouse_.._percent` variables never seem to match up with the real position. For testing purposes, I feed the method with a mouse position centered in the middle of the screen and the picture centered in the middle too. As such, the resulting `mouse_.._percent` variable should, in a perfect world, always equal 50%. For the first level, it does, but quickly wanders off when scaling. By the time I reach the first zoom breakpoint (`self.scale == 1.5`), the position has drifted to `x = 48%`, `y = 42%`.
The `self.origo_tile` is a tuple containing the x/y coordinate for the tile to be drawn on screen tile (0, 0)

I've been staring at this for hours, but can't seen to find a remedy for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How the program works:

I apologize that I didn't have enough time to apply this to your code, but I wrote the following zooming simulator.  The program allows you to zoom the same "image" multiple times, and it outputs the point of the image that would appear in the center of the screen, along with how much of the image is being shown.

---

### The code:

```
from __future__ import division #double underscores, defense against the sinister integer division

width=256 #original image size
height=256
posx=128 #original display center, relative to the image
posy=128

while 1:
    print "Display width: ", width
    print "Display height: ", height
    print "Center X: ", posx
    print "Center Y: ", posy
    anchx = int(raw_input("Anchor X: "))
    anchy = int(raw_input("Anchor Y: "))
    zmag = int(raw_input("Zoom Percent (0-inf): "))
    zmag /= 100 #convert from percent to decimal
    zmag = 1/zmag
    width *= zmag
    height *= zmag
    posx = ((anchx-posx)*zmag)+posx
    posy = ((anchy-posy)*zmag)+posy
```

---

### Sample output:

If this program outputs the following:

```
Display width: 32.0
Display height: 32.0
Center X: 72.0
Center Y: 72.0
```

---

### Explanation:

This means the zoomed-in screen shows only a part of the image, that part being 32x32 pixels, and the center of that part being at the coordinates (72,72).  This means on both axes it is displaying pixels 56 - 88 of the image in this specific example.

---

### Solution/Conclusion:

Play around with that program a bit, and see if you can implement it into your own code.  Keep in mind that different programs move the Center X and Y differently, change the program I gave if you do not like how it works already (though you probably will, it's a common way of doing it).  Happy Coding!